# How to access Windows Printer logs from PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter-3

I would like to be able to view the Printer History in Windows using PHP.

The information I require includes:

- Document name
- Page count
- Date printed

Is there any way to get this information in PHP?

Comment: what have you researched/tried thus far?

Comment: Hi, treyBake I have searched on the internet for a possible solution. couldn't find any that's the reason I asked here to know is it possible or not

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a place for questions like this, it's for specific code-issues. But, from my knowledge I don't think it's possible. I guess what you could do is create an API in another language and use PHP to query it. Aside from that, I don't think this is possible

Comment: There is no general 'printer history' as your question seems to imply. Some printers can give details on their history and printing queue, but this will vary wildly from brand to brand. So, I think it might be possible in a very specific situation, but not in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable the print log on Windows 10:

1. You need to access the Event viewer. You can search for it in Windows search.
2. Once you have Event viewer open, expand Application and Services log>Microsoft>Windows>PrintService.
3. You will see two event types here; Admin, and Operational. If you’ve never enabled print logs before, right-click Operational and from the context menu select, Properties. On the General tab, enable the ‘Enable logging’ option, and you’re good to go.

Now, for viewing this file in PHP:

```
<?php

exec('wevtutil qe Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational', $output);
var_dump($output);
```